# Drag and Drop onto Desktop Icon

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

I think this should be simple.  I have looked at similar questions here but it is not clear to my old brain as to how it should work.  I have a Windows Forms Application.  My users want to drag a file over the application icon on the desktop and execute the program with that file.  So what I would like to do is:

Accept the dropped file on the icon; start the application and place the file path details into a textbox so that the user can process it.

The application is written in C#

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the following:

```
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       // args[0] is the file
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - that gave me the direction I needed!