# Launch c# executable when files dragged to the desktop icon

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, setup-project

I have created a small c# windows application in which it converts the txt, jpg,doc,, ppt and excel files to pdf files. I have created a setup file for this application and while installing the setup file desktop shortcut icon will get created.

Now let me explain my requirement.
Drag a set of files on the application icon and it should launch the application with list of files dragged on the desktop icon.

Is there some properties or code  which i need to add.

Comment: Have you tried it? It should work out of the box.

Comment: If you're asking where the dropped icon goes in your code: I believe it's going to the `args[]` array in the `Main` method

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drag and Drop onto Desktop Icon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854966/drag-and-drop-onto-desktop-icon)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you just need to use the args from main, which will be the files:

[Drag and Drop onto Desktop Icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854966/drag-and-drop-onto-desktop-icon)

seen here.